# ¿Cómo poner puntos de interrupción de scripts de Javascript en línea en Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, depuración

Normalmente me gusta maquetar y poner estilos desde el mismo navegador, desde un nuevo tab con `about:blank`, pero quiero esta vez depurar el código javascript de la página desde allí mismo, sin crear algún archivo externo.

¿Cómo puedo lograr eso en mi Chrome Developer Tools, ya que por defecto no aparece listado en la pestaña de debugger?

## Intentos

Hasta hace unos años se hacía agregando

```
//# sourceURL=miejercicio.js
```

al final del script, pero parece que ya no funciona.

[image: chrome developer tools]

Comment: Hmmmmm, yo en el Chrome Developer Tools pongo la flechita azul encima de la línea a depurar, y cuando se ejecuta y pasa por ese punto, se para :/

Comment: @FerranMuñoz y eso funciona si tu js lo pones en un archivo, si es inline como en este no te aparece en la pestaña debugger

Comment: ¿Como que no?, funciona igual. [Mira esta imagen](https://imgur.com/a/4oiYJ7G) de una prueba que acabo de hacer. El código JS está en inline dentro del propio HTML. He puesto un breakpoint, he tocado el botón y me ha parado. ¿Donde está el problema?

Comment: @FerranMuñoz sin embargo no es un `about:blank`, tal vez se deba a eso.